# Unable to upload dSYM file to Fabric Crashlytics

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, dsym

Fabric is already integrated in project. As firebase is removing upload dSYM option from dashboard so I decided to write script suggested in Firebase.

I already set DWARF with dSYM in the build settings

I have tried following both script under Build Phase in run script

```
find dSYM_directory -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} $PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp /path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p platform \{\}
```

This Script is look like this

`find "/Users/ics.ketan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vault-dwkanmvgsftfojeyqqvahiqypywf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos" -name "*.dSYM" | xargs -I \{\} $PODS_ROOT/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp "/Users/ics.ketan/Documents/Gitlab/Vault/Code_base/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios \{\}`

And

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/upload-symbols" -gsp "${PROJECT_DIR}/GoogleService-Info.plist" -p ios "${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}"
```

I am getting following logs

`Validating build environment for Crashlytics...
Validation succeeded. Exiting because upload-symbols was run in validation mode`

Please Guide.

Comment: How did you fix this? I have spent days and I cannot get past the green "Add the SDK, then build, run, and crash your app" Crashlytics page. I am completely lost at this point. Pretty sure coming from Fabric messed me up, but I never did a real migration, only removed the SDK and replaced. I could really use some help.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0).

> Important: If you're working with an app that you previously linked
>   from Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics, pass in your Fabric API Key to
>   run the upload symbols script. That is, in the following options to
>   run the script, use `-a fabric-api-key` instead of 
>   `-gsp path/to/GoogleService-Info.plist`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use another method for Upload dSYMs file on firebase Crashlytics.

Follow this step given below for generate dSYMs of your project.

1. Generate Archive of your project and open your xcode Organizer. See below image. 
   [image]
2. Select your Project recent archive. And Right click on it And press Show In finder.[image]
3. By Right click open Show Package and Content. Select Your dSYMs file and make Zip and Upload it. 
   [image]

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue ? Fabric/Firebase have some minor glitches  processing the dSYM, but  now it is operating as expected.